# There is a faster way to use googlemaps API in Python

Tags: python, google-maps

Im currently using python to georefernce a dataset of 10512 observations, but is way slow using this code

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='APIKEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

BD2021['lat']=0
BD2021['lon']=0
for i in range(len(BD2021)):
    try:
        geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(BD2021['DIRECCION'][i]+',Barranquilla, Colombia')
        BD2021['lat'][i]=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        BD2021['lon'][i]=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    except:
        try:
            geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(BD2021['RAZON_SOCIAL'][i]+',Barranquilla, Colombia')
            BD2021['lat'][i]=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
            BD2021['lon'][i]=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
        except:
            pass
```

Theres is any faster way that you can recommend, that script have been loading for 30 mins and I dont know even its doing a good job.

Comment: Never use a bare `except:` like that! As you noticed, you have no idea whether your script is doing anything sane, or just burning through your Google Maps API quota (i.e. money).

Comment: In fact, considering what you've set `BD2021['lat']` and `lon` to, your script is doing just that – you can't index into an integer zero, so your script does nothing sane.

Comment: any recommendations? @AKX

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing at all what `BD2021` is in more detail, it's hard to definitively help, but a variation like this has more robust error handling, and also a cache, so if the same address happens to be multiple times in your dataset, the program will only geocode it once per run. (You could use a package like [`diskcache`](https://pypi.org/project/diskcache/) for a more persistent cache.)

```
from functools import cache

# ...

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key="APIKEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")


@cache
def get_geocode(address):
    return gmaps.geocode(address)


BD2021["lat"] = {}
BD2021["lon"] = {}
for i in range(len(BD2021)):
    for possible_address in (
        BD2021["DIRECCION"][i] + ",Barranquilla, Colombia",
        BD2021["RAZON_SOCIAL"][i] + ",Barranquilla, Colombia",
    ):
        try:
            geocode = get_geocode(possible_address)
            if geocode and geocode[0]:
                BD2021["lat"][i] = geocode[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
                BD2021["lon"][i] = geocode[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing {possible_address}: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"Could not find geocode for index {i}")
```

Comment: BD2021 is a dataset that contains addresses of multiple stores in the city

Comment: "a dataset" is too vague; it could be a Pandas dataframe (in which case you'd be better off using `df.map` anyway) or a list-of-dicts or anything.